# Problem using super().__init__() when doing class inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, superclass

I have this simple code to calculate the height and width of a rectangle defining 3 classes:

1. `PointL` which creates 1 point with x and y attributes.
2. `Polyline`: which just contains 4 points from the class Point.
3. `Rectangle`: which is supposed to call the points from `Polyline` and return the `height` and `width`.

However I'm getting `0.0` for both `height` and `width` all the time. I have to use the `super()` method for this.

```
    class Point:
        def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
            self.__x = x
            self.__y = y

        def set_x(self, x):
            self.__x = x

        def set_y(self, y):
            self.__y = y

        def set(self, x, y):
            self.__x = x
            self.__y = y

        def get_x(self):
            return self.__x

        def get_y(self):
            return self.__y

        def __str__(self): # <---- New __str__ method
            return "Point("+str(self.__x)+", "+str(self.__y)+")"

        x = property(get_x, set_x)
        y = property(get_y, set_y)

    class Polyline:
        def __init__(self, n=None):
            self.__p0 = Point()
            self.__p1 = Point()
            self.__p2 = Point()
            self.__p3 = Point()
            self.__n = n

        def get_p0(self):
            return self.__p0

        def get_p1(self):
            return self.__p1

        def get_p2(self):
            return self.__p2

        def get_p3(self):
            return self.__p3

        def set_p0(self, p):
            self.__p0 = p

        def set_p1(self, p):
            self.__p1 = p

        def set_p2(self, p):
            self.__p2 = p

        def set_p3(self, p):
            self.__p3 = p

        def __str__(self):
            return "Line 1 from: " + str(self.__p0) + " to " + str(self.__p2) + "\n" + "Line 2 from: " + str(self.__p1) + " to " + str(self.__p3) + "\n"

        p0 = property(get_p0, set_p0)
        p1 = property(get_p1, set_p1)
        p2 = property(get_p2, set_p2)
        p3 = property(get_p3, set_p3)

    class Rectangle(Point):
        def __init__(self, n=None, height=0.0, width=0.0):
            super().__init__(n) # <--- Call inherited constructor of Point-class
            self.__height = height
            self.__width = width

        def get_height(self):
            p0 = super().get_p0()
            p1 = super().get_p1()
            self.__height = p0.y - p1.y

        def get_width(self):
            p0 = super().get_p0()
            p1 = super().get_p1()
            self.__width = p0.x - p1.x

        def __str__(self):
            return "Rectangle dimensions: \n" + "Width: " + str(self.__width) + ", " + "Height: " + str(self.__height) + "\n"

        width = property(get_width)
        height = property(get_height)

These are my inputs:

    polyline = Polyline()
    polyline.p0.x = 0.0
    polyline.p0.y = 2.0
    polyline.p1.x = 3.0
    polyline.p1.y = 4.0
    print(polyline)
    rectangle = Rectangle()
    print(rectangle)

And these are my outputs:

    Line 1 from: Point(0.0, 2.0) to Point(0.0, 4.0)
    Line 2 from: Point(3.0, 4.0) to Point(3.0, 2.0)

    Rectangle dimensions:
    Width: 0.0, Height: 0.0
```

Comment: You design is flawed — a `Rectangle` isn't a kind of `Point`, it may _have_ or contain them, which is not the same thing. See wikipedia article on [Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)).

Comment: @martineau Could you be more explicit? I'm asking because I really don't have a clue about how to do it. Thank you for editing it, by the way.

Comment: I mean `Rectangle` should not be a subclass of `Point` — so no need to be calling `super()`, Read the article and see if that makes it clearer. If not let me know. Note also that having getters and setters isn't considered "pythonic" since the language supports properties (as you seem to be aware).

Comment: @martineau now it is clearer, I got confused but I really don't have to use the super(). But, still, I need to use the Point() objects or Polyline() in Rectangle() and I've couldn't manage to do this.

Comment: Change `Rectangle` so `Point` is no longer its base class. In `Rectangle.__init__()` you can just create two instances of `Point` and store them as attributes of the `Rectangle` instance (i.e. using something like `self.p1 = Point()` and `self.p2 = Point()`).

Comment: Thank you so much. You were very helpful.

Comment: Also, In your Rectangle class your are initializing the rectangle with the width & height.  There should be no need for any calculations. Is this really what you want or are you trying to compute the size of a rectangle that could be formed by the defined polyline?